# Adding hyper link to the footer text of a wordpress website (darina theme by besquares)

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress

I am unable to insert hyper links in my footer texts.

I have a wordpress theme (darina by bessquare) which has a space for editing the footer text in the customizer section, however the section does not accept codes only text. I want  the text I input to have hyperlink. I have tried changing the editing the footer.php file but it doesn't work as the text in the customiser overrides the footer.php file. The theme has a section for 'custom css' and 'additional code' please help me with a code I can use to override that text and have hyper links in it.

```
 </div>
    <?php } ?>
                <div class="left-block col-md-8">
                    <p class="copyright-text">
                        <?php echo esc_html(get_theme_mod('zn_footer_copyright', 'Copyright darina. 2016 - All rights reserved.' )); ?>
                    </p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</footer>
<!-- #colophon -->
<script type="text/javascript">
    var PageUrl = '<?php echo esc_js(darina_current_page_url()); ?>';
</script>
</div><!-- #page -->
```

[I need footer text with hyperlinks.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DeUtm.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Before touching the theme's template, try typing `<a href="http://youlaif.com">youlaif.com</a>` into the copyright text area of your customize menu.

If that doesn't work, just add the anchor into the PHP statement.

```
<?php echo esc_html(get_theme_mod('zn_footer_copyright', 'Copyright <a href="http://youlaif.com">youlaif.com</a>. 2016 - All rights reserved.' )); ?>
```

Comment: Thanks Sebastian. The footer customiser section text overrides even the footer.php file. There is an extra section for 'custom code' I just need a code that can overidde both the footer.php and the customizer for the footer which does not accept html... hope u understand?

Comment: Oops, I totally forgot about that. Just remove the PHP statement and place the copyright text into the `<p class="copyright-text"></p>` tag. It should look something like this: ```<p class="copyright-text">Copyright <a href="http://youlaif.com">youlaif.com</a>. 2016 - All rights reserved.</p>```